# How to shift column to row (special case) with column header in the row

Tags: tableau-api

How do I bring the column rank here to rows with the header on it. (Tableau)

[image: Clean Data]

This is the final result i want in tableau:

[image]

Comment: from the pictures it seems that you want the association of data to be changed like only year 2015 has ID 1 but in the next picture you have Id 1 in all the years. Please provide more clarity on what you want and what you have tried till date?

Comment: From the edited question, the solution can be easily achieved using a **IF..ELSEIF..ELSE..END** statement in a calculated field.

Just put in all the conditions that are needed to satisfy your requirements.

Comment: Is there any flexible way rather than putting if, else if , else .. end? This is because I can put other name such as Mary, and the ranking will change. Eg, A is 2, B is 1, C is 3 etc...

Comment: Furthermore, I have to put it under column Type

Comment: @weakincondingabc maybe Pivot might help you (https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/pivot.htm).

Comment: @weakincodingabc Are you connecting to a SQL database?

Answer (score 0):

Union the table together and create a calculated field. Then drag the aggregation to the Marks